# Is there a city/town or village equivalent of a compatriot?

Tags: single-word-requests

Like a town compatriot or city compatriot or village compatriot?

Comment: I think the usual term is a hyphenation of *fellow* e.g *a fellow-villager*, *a fellow-Norvicensian* (denizen of Norwich), *a fellow-Mancunian* (Manchester) *a fellow-Londoner* etc.

Comment: More context is needed.  'Fellow resident'?

Answer (score 0):

Vis-à-vis myself, such a person would be my townsman or my homeboy.

Comment: I've heard neither of those terms in British English.  'Homeboy' sounds like someone who works in my home; or might have homosexual connotations.

Comment: @TrevorD Or like an African servant, who sweeps and cooks (ugh).

Comment: @TrevorD \ I believe you may have the word "houseboy" in mind. "Homeboy" originated, I believe, in South Africa but is widely used in the U.S. among African Americans. Where you come by the homosexual connection God only knows.

Comment: @WS2 \ Trying to figure out the significance of (ugh) ...

Comment: *Townsman* does exist in BrE, but it's very uncommon: https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/townsman

Comment: @ProfYaffle But we do talk of *the townspeople*, or sometimes *the townsfolk*.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi Just the thought that there are still societies where one race/class of people still skivvies for another.

Comment: @WS2 Agreed - *townspeople* may sound a little odd or archaic, but it would scan okay in most contexts, I think - *The townspeople of Bury St Edmonds are up in arms at the latest proposals*, for example. I'm not sure it scales to *The townspeople of Birmingham*, though - you'd just use *people* in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

One of several options is [home folk](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/home%20folk)

> folks from your own home town.

Also, [townsman](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=townsman)

> a man who is a fellow resident of one's town.